# Can the content of python Jupyter notebook cells be manipulated from within the code running inside said notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, code-generation

I was wondering if it is possible to manipulate the content of a cell of a currently running jupyter notebook from the code running inside it.

The reason I want to do this is because I have a notebook that uses some remote API and requires an APIKEY.
I have APIKEY="".... as the contents of my first cell in the notebook.
From time to time I am required to update this API KEY.

In theory what I had in mind was that if the code that runs gets an answer from API that the token has expired or is not suitable for the current IP, It could ask me for and updated APIKEY (which I copy from the back-office of the said API) and update the said cell on its own for the next runs....

I know that there might be security issues and maybe a ton of other things to consider before actually trying to do something like this - and I also assume that in theory it should be possible to manipulate the underlying notebook file - but still was wandering if jupyter exposes some sort of an API for doing this type of in-place code manipulation.

This would also make it possible to do "self evolving" code or code generation of different sorts.

Comment: Store the api key in a file and read/update that.